# Visual Studio Live Unit Test and Old Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, live-unit-tests

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with Live Unit Testing turned on and everything is working fine until I delete a unit test.  Now the old unit test is showing as a build failure (even though it doesn't exist anymore).

How can I clear this?

Comment: You have tried a clean & rebuild or simply restarting VS?

Comment: Multiple times for each

Comment: I had to make sure. Could you please edit any errors that bubble up into your question? (If any are shown, that is)

Comment: Unit test window is up to date, the Live Unit Test is not. I'm bout to do a clean pull from git

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you close VS2019 and delete the `\.vs\{sln-name}\v16\TestStore` folder, and open VS2019 up again, all the old tests in the Live Unit Testing Window are gone.

Comment: Why don't they include this in the Options > Live Unit Testing > Delete Persisted Data ?!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is an option in Visual Studio 2019 that allows to "Delete Persisted Data" related to Live Unit Testing if data seems to be corrupted:

[image: Visual Studio 2019: Live Unit Testing - Delete Persisted Data]

Note that the mentioned button is inactive if Live Unit Testing is running. Stop Live Unit Testing to make button enabled.